# AttributeError: module 'zipfile' has no attribute 'Path'

Tags: python

Here is the code where the error occurs from:

```
    train_data = LngDataset(zipfile.Path(archive, "train/train/"))
    test_data = LngDataset(zipfile.Path(archive, "test/test/"))
    train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

archive is a zipfile which has two folders train and test.

The LngDataset() function:

```
class LngDataset(data.Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()
        self.items = list(root.iterdir())
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item = self.items[index]
        if item.name.startswith("de_"):
            y = 0
        elif item.name.startswith("en_"):
            y = 1
        elif item.name.startswith("es_"):
            y = 2
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unable to determine label for: {item.name}")
        signal, sample_rate = soundfile.read(item.open("r"))
        X = fbanks(signal, sample_rate).astype(np.float32)
        X = X[np.newaxis, ...]
        return X, y
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

I checked the documentation of zipfile. The Path attribute exists. So I dont understand how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Also, why do you think the `LngDataset` class is related to the problem? Please read about the [mcve].

Comment: Also also, are you sure that your Python version is >= 3.8?

Comment: No I cannot use Python 3.8 because to install mxnet u need python 3.7.

Comment: Then you can't use `zipfile.Path`, since it was introduced in 3.8. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#module-zipfile) is the zipfile documentation for 3.7.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent to zipfile.Path in python 3.7?